# Is there a PHP function like pg_fetch_array($result, $row) equivalent for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I am currently using pg_fetch_array($result,$i), where $row is set in a for loop. I cannot find such function in mysql. There is mysqli_fetch_array($result) but in this case it does not let me fetch a specific row. Mysql php fetch_array or fetch_row function does not let me choose only a specific row of the result set to use. I do not want to limit the select query.

Comment: Why don't you want to limit the SQL query? It is *exactly* what you should do for any database operation.

Comment: Have you tried this - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php?

Comment: @JayBlanchard it is not exactly what I have to do, as I have two queries queried once and then I am playing with variables and while loops. So it not possible to change the query for every iteration and make again queries to the database.

Comment: @u_mulder This is I think what I was exactly seeking.. Thanks!